# SqlDependency - query notification template limit reached

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldependency

I am using `SqlDependency` in a C# application to track when data gets changed. Recently, I have started getting an error indicating that the query notification template limit has been reached. The change handler is called immediately after setting up the dependency:

```
void sqlDependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            // At this point, e.Info == "TemplateLimit" and e.Type == Subscribe
        }
```

I looked up TemplateLimit and found the following info: "The subscribing query causes the number of templates on one of the target tables to exceed the maximum allowable limit."

I have tried deleting all active query notifications from the server by executing the following command:

```
KILL QUERY NOTIFICATION SUBSCRIPTION ALL
```

After doing this, there are no entries remaining in the `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` view. However, I still get the same error when setting up `SqlDependency`. It seems like the query notification templates are not being cleared, even though the subscriptions have all been removed. How can I get the `SqlDependency` to work again?

EDIT: I ended up solving the problem by restarting SQL Server (as I expected). But, I'd still like to know how to clear the templates after all the query notification subscriptions have been killed.